# CSS Transitions not applying in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

**TLDR**

Why is there no effect applied in Firefox when the background image changes.

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/3TN5A/12/)

(No FX on firefox, works on Chrome/Safari)

**Did read**

I have a slider -like component, and the content changes on callback, but when testing with Firefox the transition effect is not working.

I created a simplified Fiddle below that demonstrates the problem. The fiddle below works with Chrome/Safari but Firefox has no transition effect. The image just changes instantly.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3TN5A/12/)

```
// Code from the fiddle.
var backgroundImages = [
'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/',
'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/',
'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/', ];

var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    $('.item').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + backgroundImages[counter] + ')');
    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 3) counter = 0;
}, 2500);
```

The problem is not the transition itself, proof of this is in the modified fiddle. Where i add margin to the element, and firefox handles the transition with effects, meaning the margin is not applied "instantly" but rather smoothly, so you see the element sliding.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3TN5A/13/)

```
// Code from the modified fiddle
var backgroundImages = [
'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/',
'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/',
'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/', ];

var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    $('.item').css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + backgroundImages[counter] + ')',
        margin: counter + 'em'
    });
    counter += 1;
    if (counter == 3) counter = 0;
}, 2500);
```

I rather not use img elements for the images, i need them to be background images applied with css. I know i could do some javascript on the img elements like a simple fadeOut. But i rather use the images as background images giving me more flexibility.

Comment: it appears firefox still has not implemented transitions on background images

Comment: Even on chrome, your animation is quite buggy.

Comment: True, but the point is that its applied on Chrome, but not in FF. In the real app i work on i have done thing more complex, and im not using a setInterval method. The fiddle is just to prove my point.

Comment: I would recommend assigning the images to a few elements, and changing their display properties rather than one element's background img. In Chrome at least, the images are not being cached and the page is loading the image each time you change the src attribute. It's unnecessary network traffic for anyone on the page, even if they're inactive, and this also makes the animation look buggy, as the data for the image isn't there at the start of the transition.

Comment: In the production version they are cached, the main point with the fiddle is only the transition part, everything else can be omitted. But thanks, its always good to cache everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support background-image transitions as per [this link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052)

I am not sure this is going to be helpful to you, but you can give it a try by creating a sprite of all images you want in your slider. Sprite can be a vertical or horizontal. And depending upon the style of sprite, you can then set your `background-image` with `background-position` and then in javascript instead of changing the `background-image` for the div, just change the `background-position` of main container.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/3TN5A/18/)

Javascript:

```
var counter = 45
setInterval(function () {
    $('.container').css('background-position',counter+"px");
    counter += 45;
    if (counter>90) counter = 0;
}, 2500);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif');    
    transition: background-position 3.5s ease;
    width:43px;
    height:44px;
    background-position:0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that FF does not support it yet, well maybe its gets "fixed" after some time.

Answer (score 0):

i have updated your fiddle, please see the styles, you have to use -webkit-transition/moz-transition and o-transition..it is to ensure compatibility with all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/3TN5A/14/

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}
.item {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s;
    transition: all 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: FF, chrome, IE (opera?) have removed vendor prefix for transition property

Comment: unless i am mistaken..check this

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Thanks, but FF has had support for non-vendor prefixed transitions since version 16, and Chrome since 26.